# Is there a "science-optional" tag?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes people come in with a question tagged [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) that really isn't rooted in science at all, but uses some of the terms, like Star Trek tech speak.  It was really noticeable to me in a recent question about [storing a black hole in an ice cream truck](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/79235/black-hole-in-ice-cream-truck).

Now I'm all for creativity.  If Dippin Dots can find an excuse to use liquid nitrogen, I'm interested in what you might be able to do with the time dilation around a black hole to get that creamy texture just right!  However, when I look at the question, the only thing actually scientific about it is the words "black hole."  Everything else about it is pseudoscience at best, unadulterated by pesky real physics.

We have [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) for questions where we want real citations and mathematics, and [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) for questions which don't need such citations, but we're still looking for basic physics.  Might it be useful to introduce a [science-optional](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-optional) or [science-ish](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-ish) tag for use when you don't want to have to deal with anything like reality in your question but still want something that sounds like good "tech-speak" from a sci-fi script?  I personally value good science better than tech-speak, but I'll readily admit that tech-speak has its place and is valuable.  There are entire franchises whose illusion of science has ridden on the backs of such tech-speak!

I can't speak for every world builder out there, but I have trouble answering these science based questions unless they are at least remotely base-able in science.

It also seems like a nice place to put the questions that come in the form "Can you give me a scientific basis for my world which lacks any scientific riggor because it has some funny feature that breaks everything?"  I can see an especially high value in being able to discuss made up technologies which a skilled physicist could prove creates an infinite source of energy, something which is an anathema in anything related to science.  Authors can often side-step those pesky singularities, while science stares them down straight in their face.

Comment: You can't really be an expert on 'science-ish'. I wouldn't ever be looking specifically for 'science-ish' questions. What benefit would the tag provide?

Comment: I think there are experts on `science-ish`.  Proof would be the tech writers for Star Trek =)  Also the current raging debate over climate change (pick whichever side you think is science-ish for yourself =)  I do think there's an art form there, but its different than the art form of science based.  To me, science based is trying to put an idea on a path that doesn't have any holes, while the realm of tech speech is the art of taking something that will have big giant gaping holes and trying to distract the readers/viewers so they don't see it.

Comment: Eh, maybe it'd work. I don't think so (see linked question about handwavium), but you have good points.

Comment: I'm almost sure that you are either looking for https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/reality-check/info, or just not applying a meta-tag. Reality-check is pretty much 'internal consistancy', and requires you to specify rules. If you just want a cool sounding explanation, that sounds like an open ended list/opinion question.
In fact, the question you linked was asking about 'does this make sense?'

Comment: @Mourdos You're right that they are similar, if not the same (as you suggest).  Now obviously the tags have slightly different meanings to different people, but when I read the text for Reality Check, I get the impression that the goal is to determine if it is internally consistent or not.  For a lot of questions, the truth is that the idea in question is not self-consistent, and what's really needed is external changes to hide the self-inconsistency, rather than trying to actually fix it.

Comment: A great example woudl be anything which can create infinite energy.  A reality-check would detect that you can't create infinite energy without breaking the laws of physics, but the other question that could be interesting is "yes, I know this is broken... but how can I integrate this so seamlessly that readers don't notice."

Answer (score 3):

The "science-optional" tag would work well for questions where the limits of science are pushed beyond what is known. However, the proposed term for the tag is somewhat too ambivalent and unclear.

This problem had already been faced by science-fiction in the nineteen-thirties and their solution was to call hypothetical sciences and technologies "super-science". The "super" part simply meant "higher". So if authors wanted time-machines or faster-than-light travel this was considered to be legitimated as super-science. If time-machines were considered as impossible by current science (say, the 1930s), then their time-machines operated on super-scientific principles as yet undiscovered in the 1930s. The same justification can be applied in subsequent decades by authors in their science-fiction and correspondingly accepted by readers. Aware persons will realize that although this was called "science-fiction" it might have been better called "super-science-fiction". Certainly the term was used even into the nineteen-fifties and was part of names of some science-fiction magazines.

This isn't the only option for the name of a "science-optional" tag. "Pseudoscience" is another possibility, but that is better employed to describe truly bad and fake science. The "pseudo" of pseudoscience means "false".

"Parascience" has been used as a somewhat more respectable term for pseudoscience and is often used in areas where science is uncertain. For example, with telepathy , psychokinesis, precognition, extra-sensory perception when these phenomena are studied scientifically this is called para-psychology. The parasciences might be considered as sciences where the evidence is often fuzzy, uncertain and even plain dubious. Not quite sciences, but lurking on the fringes of being possible sciences. "the "para" part from the Greek and adds the meaning of "beside", "beyond", "wrong, irregular", especially in scientific terms. So parapsycholgy can simultaneously mean psychology that is beside psychology, beyond psychology as we know it, and wrong or irregular psychology. Presumably, depending on how legitimate you consider parapsychology as science.

Brian Stableford coined the term "metascience" in his 1979 novel *The Walking Shadow*. Looking at its Greek roots, the *meta* part of a word adds the meaning of "with", "after", and "change". Metascience, therefore, can mean that it is with science, while being after science, consequently a more advanced version of science, and science which has been changed.

The three possible terms for a "science-optional" tag all have meanings suggesting they go beyond science as is it currently known. Super-science goes back to science-fiction's pulp magazine roots. While "higher-science" gives a conceptually plausible foundation for science beyond expected science, it is possibly too florid and extravagant for a WB tag. Parascience have an unfortunate association with pseudoscience, but has good etymological roots. Metascience is somewhat uncontaminated by unfortunate associations, but persuading people to wrap their minds around the concept clearly and unequivocally might be difficult.

A further alternative term is the phrase "scientific verisimilitude" and is sometimes used for science-fiction where various literary devices (time-machines, force-fields, FTL travel) are described in ways they make them seem as if they *could apparently* be scientific phenomena. OK this usually hand-waving to fill in the gaps between what we know scientifically and what is needed to make the phenomena (no matter how unrealistic they might be in terms of legitimate science) plausible. Sometimes, the term "scientific plausibility" is used, but this can be confusing when it's used in a hard-science SF context where this means conforming to proper science.

Scientists will refer to "hand-waving". This basically means let's just assume something we don't know whether it's real or not and may not even exist is, for the sake of the argument, real. This is a conceptual process. By contrast, handwavium is a conceptual bastardization and should be put upside against a wall and summarily executed, have a stake driven through its black heart, cremated to ashes and buried at sea. You're quite right, handwavium does play well for this little black duck. Hand-waving as such is fine.

The reason for suggesting several alternative terms for a "science-optional" tag is to provide possible concepts and their related terms to describe them as a starting point for such a tag could be constructed (assuming the site wants to adopt one).

Comment: Nice alternative terms!  One thing that did bug me while writing this meta post was that science-optional didn't quite cut it, but I couldn't think of anything more.  "super-science" actually seems really promising to me because there's another connotation for the word "super:" better.  That other meaning might get people to look at the tag long enough to read its text and realize that it's a good match for their question!

Comment: I also like the idea of using an actual historical term.  It adds an inertia to the term that wouldn't be there if we made up a term.

Comment: @CortAmmon That's the main reason I proposed them. They give connections to existing traditions in science & science-fiction. Particularly super-science which goes back to early science-fiction (which does ignore proto-science-fiction, but still makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a good idea because it is not "handwavium". There are many things which allow a good story to develop, but must essentially violate either physics or the well-known limits of technology. On the other hand we have also many bogus technologies which are presented "sciency" with "quantum entanglement","vibes","waves" or "energy" and their intention shows that there is a demand of putting claims in a serious technology-speak.

If you want to build a space opera world with colonizing other solar systems 
(instead of our own) and real time engagement (no millennia), you need FTL, *there is simply no other way*. So you must either violate physics or put up theoretical entities far away of any possible technological implementation (wormholes). But this constraint has not so much influence if a story allows immersion and is believable.

*The Martian* tries extremely hard to hold to *hard-science.*
*The Expanse* Universe e.g. violates the background only insofar as it allows the progress of the story, it is *science-based*.
*Star Trek* is something which could be used as example of this label: *science-optional*. The story *needs* a scientific sounding background to allow immersion, but very few concepts are based in reality, most of the time the crew [simply utters garbage](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Technobabble).

So if a problem cannot be realistically solved with hard science, you may have at least the freedom that you accept that and build a pseudoscientific, somehow logical background which does not break the immersion.

Magic, Handwavium and Applied Phlebotinum in contrast has the severe disadvantage for a story that its limits are not immediately clear for both reader and author. It always allows the author a *Deus ex Machina* to save heroes or solve a problem.

If a hero is incarcerated in a magic world, he can teleport, phase through the material and emit disintegration rays from his fingers and *you cannot predict what the solution will be* (You can describe the limitations of your specific magic, but it really needs a whole excerpt). A science-optional world severely restricts the options and we know *without explanation* immediately that the hero is really in trouble and the solution is not so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

My concern with this tag is that what "sounds like good 'tech-speak'" differs based on the audience. People who don't know much about what is currently known by science might accept anything involving "quantum" as sounding plausible. Someone with more knowledge of what that word actually means however would scoff.

[science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) and [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) work because they have pretty firm definitions for what we want. Anything *without* those tags is essentially in the area you're talking about.

If there is some thing that your world needs to have, and you want to find a justification that, while not necessarily being scientific will at least give some people enough deniability to swallow it, then you should just ask for that in the question itself. This will also give you the opportunity to explain exactly the scope of what "good tech-speak" would be for your needs, rather than us having to guess.

Furthermore, I don't think the tag would be helpful to sub-communities of users. Some people are a lot more interested in questions that are hard-science than things that are more speculative, so giving them a tag is helpful to letting them find questions of interest. By contrast, I don't think there is a sub-community of people looking specifically to answer "good tech-speak" questions.

Comment: Without trying to be a contrarian it seems to me that there more interest in speculative questions in science-oriented ones. While the hard-science tag may be well defined it may confuse some, because hard-science SF is closer to science-based tag than hard-science tag questions.